# Grouping and Counting Multiple Values in a Column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm trying to generate a report for how many jobs we do in each city each day, also showing where we get that job from.

I have a column with a number of suburbs (roughly 300-350). These are suburbs in two cities. I'd like to group these suburbs into their appropriate city and also show the count.

I was thinking something like:

```
Site_Suburb LIKE '%Suburb1%' OR LIKE '%Suburb2%' AS `City1` 
Site_Suburb LIKE '%Suburb3%' OR LIKE '%Suburb4%' AS `City2
```

(Just rough pseudo code to help give you an idea..)

Overall I need the report to `GROUP BY Date`, `City` and `Job Source`

I have this query so far:

```
SELECT
from_unixtime(`reservations`.`created`) AS `formatted_date`,
`reservations`.`start_date` AS `start_date`,
`reservations`.`site_suburb` AS `site_suburb`,
`reservations`.`job_source` AS `job_source`,

DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`reservations`.`created`)) AS date,

COUNT(`reservations`.`created`) as group_by_count from `reservations`

GROUP BY
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`reservations`.`created`)),
`reservations`.`site_suburb`,
`reservations`.`job_source`

order by from_unixtime(`reservations`.`created`) desc
```

Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: post some sample data to help us understand what it is you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    case
         when Site_Suburb LIKE '%Suburb1%' OR Site_Suburb LIKE '%Suburb2%' AS `City1` 
         when Site_Suburb LIKE '%Suburb3%' OR Site_Suburb LIKE '%Suburb4%' AS `City2 

    else site_suburb end Suburb
    ,job_source
    ,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`reservations`.`created`)) AS date
    ,count(*) as jobs

from 
    reservations

group by
   case
         when Site_Suburb LIKE '%Suburb1%' OR LIKE '%Suburb2%' AS `City1` 
         when Site_Suburb LIKE '%Suburb3%' OR LIKE '%Suburb4%' AS `City2 

    else site_suburb end 
  ,job_source
  ,DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`reservations`.`created`))
```

Comment: Hi lookslikeanevo, thanks for your reply.
I'm using:
`SELECT
CASE
  WHEN site_suburb LIKE '%Coorparoo%' OR site_suburb LIKE '%Mansfield%' THEN 'Brisbane'
  WHEN site_suburb LIKE '%Helensvale%' THEN 'Gold Coast'
END
FROM reservations;`

That seems to work great, however is there an easier way to add a heap of variables (I've got 300-350). Rather than entering "OR LIKE '%%' over and over?

Is there some simple syntax like (suburb1|suburb2|suburb3) ?

Comment: @Azyrus an easier way would be to create a lookup table and join it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is `in`:

```
select (case when Site_Suburb in ('Suburb1', 'Suburb2') then 'City1'
             when Site_Suburb in ('Suburb3', 'Suburb4') then 'City2'
             else site_suburb
        end) Suburb,
       job_source,
       DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`reservations`.`created`)) AS date,
       count(*) as jobs
from reservations
group by suburb, job_source, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`reservations`.`created`));
```

This obviously won't work for all cases, because `in` looks for an exact match with no wildcards.

Really, the best way to handle this is with a lookup table that has `site_suburb` in one column and `city` in another.